# WPF Multiline TextBlock CenterAlignment Issue

Tags: wpf, multiline, textblock

I'm having an issue with multiline text blocks where it is not center aligning properly

The text is coming like

```
abcde\nabc
```

This comes out

```
  abcde
  abc
```

What I want is

```
  abcde
   abc
```

This seems a simple thing and I would have thought that the textblock would center align like that automatically but it does not seem to.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Try the `TextAlignment` property instead of `HorizontalAlignment`. First one is the alignment of text in the `TextBlock`, second the alignment of the `TextBlock` in the parent container.

Comment: Yeah, that's the solution thanks!

Answer (score 20):

[TextBlock.TextAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textalignment.aspx) should do what you're asking for.