# TextBox splitting lines in wrong place

Tags: c#, xaml

I've written the following `TextBox` for `xaml`:

```
<TextBox Padding="20,17,20,17"  BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="True" 
TextBlock.LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" TextBlock.LineHeight="24" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Ticket.MessageContent}"  
FontSize="14" FontFamily="HelveticaNeue" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
```

However, it is in a dynamic window that messes up the lines the further you expand the window. I believe it has to do with the `TextWrapping` but I have tried `WrapWithOverflow` and this did not solve the problem. I have also tried to add a `StackPanel` with a `Orientation=Horizontal` but this makes the text go over the page. Does anyone know why this is happening?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show what the value of `Ticket.MessageContent` is (including any linebreaks). Also, please post what the desired result would look like.

Comment: Setting _"TextWrapping"_ to _"Wrap"_ works perfectly for me - other than when there are embedded newline characters & a break always occurs there. Are you sure there are not newline characters after _"anything"_, _"was"_ & _"to"_?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting TextBox properties with MaxLines="1" TextWrapping="NoWrap". 
Hope you can get something from this reference too > [Multiline Text in a WPF Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449276/multiline-text-in-a-wpf-button)

Comment: This just only allows one line